# How to insert a docx document into another docx at certain position without altchunk

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

Is there a way to insert a whole docx document into another one without using altchunks? The problem is that after insertion I have to merge the resulted doc with another one using **DocumentBuilder** from OpenXml Powertools and it does not support documents that contains altchunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to come up with a solution. In order to insert a document at a certain position I split the original document into two sources for the **DocumentBuilder**, then I created a source from the document to be inserted. In the end I built a new document with these 3 sources and it seems to be working just fine.

I am looking for the paragraph to split the original document by a placeholder, for example "*@@insert@@*".

Bellow is the code if anyone needs it.

```
var paragraph = DestinationDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<OpenXmlParagraph>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.InnerText.Contains(placeHolder));

                if (paragraph != null)
                {
                    var idOfParagraph =
                    DestinationDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<OpenXmlParagraph>()
                        .ToList()
                        .IndexOf(paragraph);

                    //save and close current destination document
                    SaveChanges(destinationFilePath, false);

                    var sources = new List<Source>();

                    var originalDocument = new WmlDocument(destinationFilePath);

                    sources.Add(new Source(originalDocument, 0, idOfParagraph, true)); // add first part of initial document

                    var documentToBeInserted = new WmlDocument(docFilePath);
                    sources.Add(new Source(documentToBeInserted, true)); // add document to be inserted

                    sources.Add(new Source(originalDocument, idOfParagraph + 1, true)); // add rest of initial document


                    var newDestinationDocument = DocumentBuilder.BuildDocument(sources); // build new document
                    newDestinationDocument.SaveAs(destinationFilePath); // save

                    // re-open destination document
                    DestinationDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(Path.GetFullPath(destinationFilePath), true);
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing solution, I'm encounter this question too.